# Common divisor of $a+b$ and $ab$.

Tags: prime-numbers, divisibility

If $\gcd(a,b) =1$.
Why does $\gcd(a+b,ab)=1$ ?

I know that if $\gcd(a,b)=1$ then there exists $u$ and $v$ where $au+bv=1$. But I can't seem to relate it to $a+b$ and $ab$.

Comment: possible duplicate of [If $(a,b)=1$ then prove $(a+b, ab)=1$.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/257434) or [If $\gcd(a, b) = 1$ then $\gcd(ab, a+b) = 1$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/566193) or [$\operatorname{gcd}(ab,a+b)=1$ if $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/901117)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since
$ab-a(a+b)
=-a^2
$
and
$ab-b(a+b)
=-b^2
$,
if
$d$ divides both
$ab$ and $a+b$,
then $d$ divides both
$a^2$ and $b^2$.

Since
$(a, b) = 1$,
$(a^2, b^2) = 1$,
so $d = 1$.

Comment: @OP Note that it requires *proof* that $\ (a,b) = 1\,\Rightarrow\, (a^2,b^2)=1\ \ $

Comment: The primes dividing a are the ones that divide $a^2$ and similarly for b.

Comment: Which, again, requires *proof* (e.g. it may fail in some quadratic number rings where irreducibles need not be prime). Probably, for proof, you have in mind the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic (*existence* and *uniqunesss* of prime factorizations).

Answer (score 4):

If $(a,b)=1$, [Bezout's Identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity) says there are $x,y$ so that $ax+by=1$. Then
$$
(a^2x+b^2y)(\color{#C00000}{x+y})-(a-b)^2\color{#C00000}{xy}=(ax+by)^2=1
$$
Therefore, $(x+y,xy)=1$.

Comment: I just found that I answered [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/257434). At least my answer there was different. Looking at the other answers there, I see that mine is very close to Henning Makholm's there.

Comment: I was writing a Bezout proof for you as you were writing this - see my Bezout answer here.

Comment: It is pretty close to the answer I mentioned in the comment above. This question should definitely be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Yeah, there's only so many ways to Bezout. I only saw your answer (and link) after I posted mine. There are far too many of these questions to remember them all, and they are not easy to locate by search.

Comment: There are four duplicates mentioned in comments to the question. As long as this question is not deleted, these five questions will remain linked, not just related.

Comment: I didn't reload the page since I first opened it, so I didn't see those either. Perhaps there should be dupe notifications too. And oh for a way to search on expressions...

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: $a(a+b) - ab = a^2$ and $b(a+b) - ab = b^2$ so that $\mathrm{gcd}(a+b, ab)$ divides $a^2$ and $b^2$.

Comment: Beat you by 5 seconds. Great minds think alike.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a direct proof for those who enjoy Bezout fiddling.

$\quad \begin{align}
\gcd(a,b)=1\ \Rightarrow\ 1 &=\,  j a + k b\quad\text{for some }\ j,k\in\Bbb Z\\
&=\, (j\!-\!k)a + k(a+b)\\
&=\, (k\!-\!j)b  + j(a+b),\ \ \ \text{so multiplying this with above}\\
\Rightarrow\ 1 &=\quad\, m\,ab + n (a+b)\ \ \ \text{for some }\ m,n\in\Bbb Z \\
\Rightarrow\ 1 &=\ \gcd (ab,\ a+b)
\end{align}$

**Remark** $\ $ Using gcd laws eliminates the obfuscatory Bezout coefficients

$$ (a,c)(b,c) = (ab,c(a,b,c)) = (ab,c)\ \ {\rm if}\ \ (a,b,c) = 1\qquad$$

Yours is the special case $\ c = a+b,\ $ and $\ (a,b)=1\ \,(\Rightarrow\, (a,b,c)=1)$

Comment: Bill does Bezout!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** $\ $ By [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/673192/242): $\ (c,a)=1=(c,b)\,\Rightarrow\, (c,ab)=1.\ $  Let $\ c = a+b.$

**Remark** $\ $ More generally $\ (a\!+\!b,\, {\rm lcm}(a,b))\, =\, (a,b).\,$ [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/21626/242) for a few proofs.