# Find the unknowns from LCM HCF relation.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Consider $2$ numbers $x,y$ such that $\frac{x+y}{lcm(x,y)}=\frac{7}{12}$, and it is given that hcf(x,y) is $4$.

How to find $\mathbf{x,y}$.

---

I have tried the question like this.
\begin{align*}
  \frac{x + y}{(x\cdot y)/4} \Rightarrow \frac{4(x+y)}{x\cdot y} &= \frac{7}{12}\\
48x+ 48y &= 7xy\\
48x &= 7xy-48y\\
48x &= y\cdot(7x-48)\\
y &= \frac{48\cdot x}{7x-48}\\
\end{align*}

As $y$ is a positive number the denominator have to be $<0$, so $x \ge 7$. Now If I put $x =7$
I get $y = \frac{48\cdot 7}{49-48} = 336$. But

lcm(7,336) is 336
and $\frac{7+336}{336} \neq \frac{7}{12}$. Where am I making mistake? the hcf is not 4 for (7,336)

---

second method I Tried was,
$x = 4a, y =4b.$
now ,

\begin{align*}
  \frac{4a + 4b}{4\cdot a\cdot b} &= \frac{7}{12} \\ 
  \frac{a+b}{a\cdot b} &= \frac{7}{12} \\ 
    \frac{a+b}{a\cdot b} &= \frac{7}{12} \\ 
   \frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b} &= \frac{7}{12}\\
   \frac{1}{a} &= \frac{7}{12} - \frac{1}{b}\\
   \frac{1}{a} &= \frac{7b-12}{12b}\\
or\\
a &= \frac{12b}{7b-12}
\end{align*}

so $b\ge 2$ to get an integer, now for $b=2, a= 12. \Rightarrow x=48, y=4$, also if I choose b=2, the hcf is not 4, so if I put $b=3, a = 4 \Rightarrow (12, 16)$ , here the hcf and lcm are,
$4$ and $48$ respectively.and $\frac{12+16}{48} = \frac{7}{12}$.

What is the mistake I am making. ?

Comment: Is  HCF it Half Convex Function theorem?

Comment: No sorry , it is the Highest common factor ,

Comment: Id est, $\gcd$, OK

Comment: you are not choosing the right numbers I think. For example in your second method, you know HCF is $4$ which means one of the $a$ or $b$ will be odd number. So please check on that. It will not be true for all $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 1):

For your first method since hcf(x,y)=4 then $4|x$ and $4|y$ so clearly $x=7$ is not  a possibility since $4\not|7.$ So you can only choose $x$ of the form $4k$ for some $k\in\mathbb N.$

In fact the possible integer solutions are given by $(x,y)=(-48,6),(6,-48),(7,336),(7,48)$ and $(12,16).$ Then checking, the correct one is $(12,16).$

For your second method you have $x=4a$ and $y=4b$ then $$\frac{a+b}{ab}=\frac{7}{12}=\frac{7}{3\cdot 4}=\frac{3+4}{3\cdot 4}$$

so clearly you can have $(a,b)=(3,4),(4,3)$ (and the other solutions are $(2,12)$ and $(12,2)$ which are not valid since they have a common divisor of $2$).

So setting $(a,b)=(3,4)$ we have $(x,y)=(12,16)$ and setting $(a,b)=(4,3)$ you have $(x,y)=(16,12).$

Answer (score 0):

From the point you get to, $y = \frac{48\cdot x}{7x-48}$

As HCF of $x, y$ is $4$, try $x = 8, 12, ... \, (\ge 7)$. $8$ is not possible as that gives $y = 48$ and hence HCF of $8$. So next try with $x=12$ and you get $y=16$ and those are your numbers.

Your second method gives $b = 3, a = 4$ which is the same. In your second method, you have defined $x = 4a, y = 4b$ so HCF of $a$ and $b$ will be $1$. If you choose $b = 2$, you get $a = 12$ and HCF of $a, b$ is $2$ which is not what you are looking for. So, go with $b = 3$ and that works.

Answer (score 0):

[Cancelling](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1213430/242) $\,4\,$ from our gcd $\,(x,y)=4\,\Rightarrow\, \color{#c00}{(a,b)=1}$ thus  $\,\color{#0a0}{(a\!+\!b,\,ab) = 1}\,$ by [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1187102/242).

So $\ \dfrac{a\!+\!b}{\color{#90f}{ab}}\! =\! \dfrac{7}{\color{#90f}{12}}\,$  are $\rm\color{#0a0}{reduced}$, [thus](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/825871/242) $\,\color{#90f}{ab = 12},\,$ so  $\,a,b\,$ are $\rm\color{#c00}{coprime}$ factors of $12$, so $\,a,b = \begin{cases}\!3,4\\\! 4,3\end{cases}$

So the "mistake" was not invoking enough number theory (viz. the $3$ linked well-known theorems).

The first method boils down to the second, but scaled by the gcd $4$ so their is no need to treat it separately. Generally, as explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3658798/242) *homogeneous* problems like this are usually simplified by reducing to the *coprime* case by cancelling the gcd throughout (using gcd & lcm distributive laws).

Comment: Here $\,(m,n) := \gcd(m,n)\ \ $  [standard number theory notation]